# How to set a time interval to each radio button on JS?

Tags: javascript

How do I set an interval to each radio button such that when each button is clicked, button would call out the method randomArray() to randomize an element from an array every few secs.. Low would be every 3 sec, med every 2 sec, and high every 1sec.

```
       <html><table><tr>
        <td width="20%">The difficulty level:</td>
        <td width="20%">
        <input type="radio" name="level" id ="low" onclick="difficulty()" value="low">low</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" id="medium" onclick="difficulty()" 
        value="medium">medium</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" id="high" onclick="difficulty()" value="high">high</input>
        </td></tr></table>
<script> 
function randomArray() 
{
    var option1 = getRandom();
    var option2 = getRandom(); 
    var option3 = getRandom();
    
    
    if (option1 == option2 || option1 == option3) 
    {
        option1 = getRandom();  
        //console.log(option1);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("option1").value = option1;
    }
    
    if (option2 == option1 || option2 == option3) 
    {
        option2 = getRandom();  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("option2").value = option2;
    }

    if (option3 == option2 || option3 == option1) 
    {
        option3 = getRandom();  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("option3").value = option3;
    }
}
function difficulty()
{
    if (document.getElementById("low").checked() = true)
    {
        var low = setInterval(randomArray, 3000); 
        
    } else if (document.getElementById("medium").checked() = true)
    {
        var med = setInterval(randomArray, 2000); 
    } else 
    {
        var high = setInterval(randomArray, 1000);
    }
} </script></html>
```

Comment: You need the function randomArray?

Comment: The markup is badly off, `td` can't exist without `table` and `tr` elements, `input` is an empty element, it must not have a closing tag, inline listeners are bad practice ...

Comment: @AndreaViviani i did not put in previously but i just did!

Comment: @Teemu I do have the td, table and tr tags in my HTML file just that i did not put it in sorry about that

Comment: Okay. Now, more JS and less HTML is better, see [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ky8agL5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is refactoring of code. Checked is property not a function.

```js
let interval;

function difficulty(target) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  if (target.checked) {
    interval = setInterval(randomArray, target.value);
  }
}

function randomArray() {
  console.log('Calling randomArray');

}
```

```html
<td width="20%">The difficulty level:</td>
<td width="20%">
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="1000" onclick="difficulty(this)" />low
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="2000" onclick="difficulty(this)" />medium
  <input type="radio" name="level" value="3000" onclick="difficulty(this)" />high
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```js
var interval = null;

function randomArray(){
console.log(1)}
function difficulty(e)
{
  var intervalSpeed = parseInt(e.getAttribute('intervalTime'),10);
  console.log(intervalSpeed*1000);
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(randomArray, intervalSpeed*100); // here you can set it intervalSpeed*1000 for seconds. I just want to show it in milliseconds
}
```

```html
<td width="20%">The difficulty level:</td>
        <td width="20%">
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='3' id ="low" onclick="difficulty(this)" value="low">low</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='2' id="medium" onclick="difficulty(this)" 
        value="medium">medium</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='1' id="high" onclick="difficulty(this)" value="high">high</input>
        </td>
```

if you want full code:

```js
var a=20;


var getRandom = function(array) {
var max = 60;
var min = 10;
  const ARRAY_LENGTH = array;
  return Array.apply(null, {length: ARRAY_LENGTH}).map(x=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*(max - min)+min));
}

function isArrayEqual(arrayA,arrayB){
if(arrayA.length != arrayB.length) return false;
arrayA.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
arrayB.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
var vis = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
  if( arrayA[i] != arrayB[i] ){
  vis = 1;
  break;
  }
}
if(vis == 1) return false;
return true;
}

function randomArray() 
{
    var option1 = getRandom(a);
    var option2 = getRandom(a); 
    var option3 = getRandom(a);
    
    
    if (isArrayEqual(option1, option2) || isArrayEqual(option1, option3)) 
    {
        option1 = getRandom(a);  
        //console.log(option1);
    } else {
        //document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = option1;
        console.log(option1);
    }
    
    if (isArrayEqual(option2, option1) || isArrayEqual(option2, option3))
    {
        option2 = getRandom(a);  
    } else {
        //document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = option2;
        console.log(option2);
    }

    if (isArrayEqual(option3, option2) || isArrayEqual(option3, option1)) 
    {
        option3 = getRandom(a);  
    } else {
        //document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = option3;
        console.log(option3);
    }
}

var interval = null;


function difficulty(e)
{
  var intervalSpeed = parseInt(e.getAttribute('intervalTime'),10);
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(randomArray, intervalSpeed*1000); // here you can set it intervalSpeed*1000 for seconds. I just want to show it in milliseconds
}
```

```html
<td width="20%">The difficulty level:</td>
        <td width="20%">
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='3' id ="low" onclick="difficulty(this)" value="low">low</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='2' id="medium" onclick="difficulty(this)" 
        value="medium">medium</input>
        <input type="radio" name="level" intervalTime='1' id="high" onclick="difficulty(this)" value="high">high</input>
        </td>
```